# Java Thread Safe Lazy Initialization

Tags: java, thread-safety, lazy-initialization

I have a web application. Running on `tomcat` and multiple threads serving the `Servlet` calls.

I have a `User` class, an `Account` class, and an 1AccountContext` class.

`Accounts` can have multiple `Users`.

Only 1 instance of `AccountContext` should be maintained in memory per `Account`.

When a user makes a log in call via the servlet: if the `AccountContext` exists, return that. Otherwise, initialize it.

Below is the code that I wrote to initialize the context. Does this code look like it will
do what I want while being thread safe?

`ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP` is a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

```
public static AccountContext getAccountContext(Account account) {
    AccountContext accountContext = ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP.get(account);
    if(accountContext == null){
        synchronized(account){
            if(ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP.get(account) == null)
                accountContext = new AccountContext(account);
                //Creating the AccountContext is expensive, 
                //i'd like it if it was only done once.
                ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP.put(account,accountContext);        
            }else{
                accountContext = ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP.get(account);
            }
        }
    }
    return accountContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is not thread safe **unless you guarantee that all threads have the same instance of account and there is no way to have two Account objects representing the same "account"**, consider this scenario: two threads have an Account object each, representing the same account, they both call getAccountContext(), first thread get suspended right after the line if(accountContext == null) but before starting the initialization, then second thread gets to this same lime, verify that accountContext is null and proceeds to create the AccountContext, then the first thread is given again CPU time, as this first thread has already "verified" that accountContext is null, it will proceed to create another instance.

Try by synchronizing using the map itselt (ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP) rather than each Account object.

If you don't want to synchronize on the map because it would cause other thread to wait for an expensive AccountContext to be created, then try this:

- Create a new class: **AccountContextBuilder**: an unexpensive-to-create class that builds an expensive **AccountContext**. This class will contain a builder method to create an **AccountContext** or return a previously created one.
- Make your map to contain instances of **AccountContextBuilder** rather than **AccountContext**.
- Synchronize on the map (anyway you need to have it synchronized), this time it wont penalize other threads, because you are going to create a "cheap" builder object.
- Finally, the thread use this builder to get access to the **AccountContext**, this way other threads aren't penalized because of other AccountContexts.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I can't guarantee that they are the same Account object.  But I also don't want to synchronize on the map itself because I don't want threads on different accounts waiting for expensive AccountContext creation.  I'd like it if the context creations for different accounts to be done in parallel, and then pay the synchronization penalty only when adding to the hashmap.

Comment: @user2537426 I've edited my post to add a possible solution to your problem, yshavit's solution is also a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent` atomic method instead of synchronization which is specially designed for such situations. This is how it's used:

```
AccountContext accountContext = ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP.get(account);
if (accountContext == null){
    accountContext = new AccountContext(account);
    AccountContext accountContextOld = ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP.putIfAbsent(account, accountContext);        
    if (accountContextOld != null) {
         accountContext = accountContextOld;
    }
}
return accountContext;
```

Comment: I'm also trying to avoid having multiple threads kickoff the expensive AccountContext creation.

Answer (score 0):

As @morgano pointed out, this only works if `account` is the same instance for all equal accounts. In addition, the `Map` must be thread-safe -- which often means using a `ConcurrentHashMap` or similar. If your map isn't thread-safe, then the `get` on the first line isn't thread-safe -- lots of bad things can go wrong.

One thing you can do is to stripe your locks. Create an array of N objects (literally `Object` is fine). When you need a lock for the `synchronized` block, get it from `account.hashCode() % locksArray.length`, and then synchronize on that object. This means you'll be able to create many `AccountContext`s in parallel, as long as their `Account`s have different `hashCode() % N`. On average, this should give you good performance; obviously it assumes that `Account` has a suitable `hashCode()` override.

```
private final Object[] locks = createLocks();

private static Object[] createLocks() {
    Object[] locks = new Object[20]; // or whatever
    for (int i = 0; i < locks.length; ++i) {
        locks[i] = new Object();
    }
}

if (accountContext == null) {
    Object lock = locks[account % locks.length];
    synchronized (lock) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Lastly, this is a minor thing, but in the synch block, where you have:

```
if(ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP.get(account) == null) {
    ...
```

I would do:

```
accountContext = ACCOUNT_CONTEXT_MAP.get(account);
if (accountContext == null) {
    ...
```

Then you don't need the `else` block.

Comment: There is a very nice striped lock implementation in guava:  com.google.common.util.concurrent.Striped   http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, looks like what I need.  My account hashcode is based on a UUID that I assign on account creation.  Based on your suggestion I found and checked out the Striped class from Guava collections.  Do you see any tradeoff for using your approach vs the Striped which returns a java util concurrent Lock?  ** posted before I saw Keith's reply...